# Having issues creating a for loop for a list created in JS

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to for loop the H1 object through a list 10 times. I'm not sure where I went wrong any help would be appreciated.

```js
var headOne = document.createElement("H1");
headOne.textContent = "Hello World";
document.body.appendChild(headOne);

var newOrderedList = document.createElement('OL');
newOrderedList.setAttribute("id", "OLJS");
document.body.appendChild(newOrderedList);

var helloWorld = document.getElementById("OLJS");

for (var i = 0; headOne < 10; i++){
  var listItems = document.createElement("li");
  listItems.innerHTML = headOne[i];
  helloWorld.append(listItems);
}
```

Comment: headone is not an array its and html element ```<h1>Hello World</h1>``` You are trying to loop through an html element

Comment: I am trying to loop the h1 10 times. I can't figure out how though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop 10 times then do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // Do something
}
```

And in your case if you are trying to access each letter of `headOne` element and append it to the `helloWorld` list then you can do the following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < headOne.textContent.length; i++) {
  let listItems = document.createElement('li')
  listItems.textContent = headOne.textContent[i]
  helloWorld.append(listItems)
}
```

You might also want to read more about [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration?retiredLocale=ar)

Comment: I don't need to access each letter, I need to loop the h1 10 times but in an ordered list.

Comment: @JLB Do you mean you want the content of `h1`  to be added to a list 10 times?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var headOne = document.createElement("H1");
headOne.textContent = "Hello World";
document.body.appendChild(headOne);

var newOrderedList = document.createElement('OL');
newOrderedList.setAttribute("id", "OLJS");
document.body.appendChild(newOrderedList);

//var helloWorld = document.getElementById("OLJS");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var listItems = document.createElement("li");
  listItems.innerHTML = "order list item " + (i + 1);
  newOrderedList.append(listItems);
}
```